# aws distributed load test result and jmeter result is different

Tags: amazon-web-services, performance, jmeter, load-testing

I have executed load testing using jmeter and aws distibuted load test. But results are different between jmeter and cloudfront. Here are the image given below:

[image]

I do not know why

Answer (score 1):

I know why. You're running different tests, that's why you're getting different results.

- With "aws distributed load test" (whatever it is) you're running a "1 second test"
- With JMeter you're running [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers with 200 virtual users until completion

Assuming the other configuration is the same I would recommend removing this `HOLD FOR = 1s` from your "aws distributed load test" and it should make results more or less the same

I would also recommend reconsidering your workload pattern as you may or may not achieve this "200 users concurrency" assuming you have only one iteration, normally you should:

1. [Increase the load gradually](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#thread_group), this way you will be able to correlate increasing load with changing metrics like response time, throughput, number of errors, etc.
2. Let the test to run some time at "plateau" phase, i.e. set number of loops/iterations to forever and limit the test duration:

   [image]

   so you will have the workload pattern looking like:

   [image]
3. Preferably [ramp-down the load again gradually](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-ramp-down-on-jmeter) to see whether system performane recover as the load decreases

Comment: In aws I am running jmeter script